# read() method not looping in proper size?

Tags: java

Please help me understand this. I want to input 5 numbers using the read() method in BufferedReader. But why I couldn't input 5 numbers even If I called it 5 times?

```
BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    inp.read();
    inp.read();
    inp.read();
    inp.read();
    inp.read();
```

When run: (These numbers are input)

1

2

3

Process finished with exit code 0

Expected input result: (Any single numbers as long as I can input 5 numbers)

1

2

3

4

5

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to *demonstrate* that that the first loop won't repeat 5 times.

Comment: FWIW, the three loops are reading different things.  The first one reads 5 characters.  The second one reads 5 lines.  The first one reads 5 (decimal) numbers.   And the most likely reason that the first one doesn't read 5 characters is that there are not 5 characters left in the stream.

Comment: You didn't tell us the input you give to the program. Also, mind that `System.in` is buffered so it won't read until `return` is pressed.

Comment: Isn't the read() method supposed to read single character? A single character 5 times not 5 characters?

Comment: You didn't tell us how the three lines were produced either. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I already stated I can loop 5 times. I see it as redundant. But I edited it as you wish. It's the same input as above. Let me repeat my question... why is the read() method in this code not looping 5 times but 3?

Comment: There is still nothing here that produces any output at all, let alone the output you claim, and there is still no sign of what the input looks like either.

Comment: *"Let me repeat my question..."* - We cannot answer your question, unless you provide a **real** [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Click on the link and read what it says.

Comment: There's no output. I just want to be able to input 5 numbers using read() method. Somehow, I couldn't input 5 numbers even in this code:  BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)); inp.read(); inp.read(); inp.read(); inp.read(); inp.read();

Comment: When you type 1 and press enter, it enters 2 characters.

Comment: How do you know? What, for the fourth time, does the input look like? Where, for the fourth time, is the code that produces the output you have posted? The output that you claimed doesn't exist? That your question is about?

Comment: @user207421 when you type into a terminal it echos the result, so if their terminal will show 1, then they press enter and they type 2 etc. Until the program finishes and they see the prompt again.

Comment: @StephenC If you look at the current code they have, I think you can agree it is a minimal reproducible example. It does not include import statements or the main method declaration though. Do you think it needs to have those bits too?

Comment: Technically, no it is not a minimal reproducible example.  And yes it does need those bits,  But I don't think it matters.  1) The accepted answer contains the insight that the OP is missing; i.e. read reads characters not numbers.  2) But we said that in the comments anyway; e.g. my second one. 3) I don't think any purpose would be served by reopening (see point 1).

Comment: @StephenC The only purpose I see re-opening it would accomplish is to indicate that it is no-longer offtopic.  It seems like they made effort to improve their question, but it is true they probably will not get more insightful input by re-opening the question. Your first comment is a bit outdated because it doesn't read decimal numbers.

Comment: @matt - Well yea.  It refers to two parts of the OP's question that they has deleted.  But obviously I can't edit it because it is a comment.  And that the part that is not out of date is the part that I was referring to.

Comment: I don't think leaving a -2 question open *solely* to indicate that it is (now) on topic is a worthwhile thing to do.  Saying "it is now on topic" achieves the same thing. And technically, it still isn't because that is not a minrep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is `read` reads character, not lines. So your getting 1 int out of read which includes the line ending. Try switching to `BufferedReader.readline()`.

Also you're using the term 'loop' which implies something different than calling a method 5 times.

Here is an example to demonstrate.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Borked{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            int j = read.read();
            System.out.println(i + ", " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I enter 1 then 2 then 3, you can see two characters each time and it ends early.

> 1
>   0, 49
>   1, 10
>   2
>   2, 50
>   3, 10
>   3
>   4, 51

The first number is the index representing the number of times called, the second number is the character read. 10 is a new line. When it is 1 character on the line, that is the value I entered.

Comment: From what I understand, the readLine() will terminate once we press enter. But how about the read() method? How does it terminate?

Comment: @ratRiot01 The read **returns** when you press enter on the first iteration. On the second call to read it returns immediately because it has a character in the buffer waiting to be read.